# I don't know what is wrong in my speech recognition program

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

Exception in Tkinter callback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/choihyomin/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/choihyomin/Documents/GitHub/Doby_OS/main.py", line 9, in DobbyIsListening
    dobby.dobyisfree()
  File "/Users/choihyomin/Documents/GitHub/Doby_OS/dobby.py", line 15, in dobyisfree
    audio = r.listen(source,timeout = 2)
  File "/Users/choihyomin/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 618, in listen
    raise WaitTimeoutError("listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start")
speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError: listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start
```

Hi, I'm a student who studies python.
I'm making AI using SpeechRecognition module.
I saw a YouTube tutorial and coded.
I installed `SpeechRecognition` and `PyAudio`. But it is not working:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("도비는 듣고 있어요!")
    audio = r.listen(source,timeout = 2)
```

This is the part where the error comes in my code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried increasing the `timeout` from 2 ?

Comment: Actually This code worked yesterday night..